# Memory not being released for UICollectionView of large images

Tags: memory-management, uiimage, nsmutablearray, automatic-ref-counting, uicollectionview

I have an NSMutableArray of 15 elements, all of them strings. The strings refer to an image name that is stored locally in the app (images approximately 640x640 each). I am displaying the array of images in a UICollectionView.

When I reload the collectionView to display the images, my memory usage shoots up as you would expect displaying large png's (though its footprint is much larger than I expected).

The real problem is that memory used by these images is never freed. So despite me removing all objects from the array, removing the collectionView and setting everything to nil, none of the memory is freed.

Why is this? I would expect my memory to return to it's original level if I removed these objects and removed the ViewController.

UPDATED: Code snippet

ViewController.m

```
@implementation ViewController

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"photoCell";

-(void)viewDidLoad{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.photoCollectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, self.view.frame.size.width, 320) collectionViewLayout:self.photoSpringFlowLayout];
    [self.photoCollectionView setDataSource:self];
    [self.photoCollectionView setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addSubview:self.photoCollectionView];
    [self.photoCollectionView registerClass:[PhotoPreviewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    self.imagesAray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"photo1", @"photo2", @"photo3", @"photo4", @"photo5", @"photo6", @"photo7", @"photo8", @"photo9", @"photo10", @"photo11", @"photo12", @"photo13", @"photo14", @"photo15", nil];

    [self.photoCollectionView reloadData];
}


#pragma mark - UICollectionView Methods

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return self.imagesArray.count;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    PhotoPreviewCell *cell = (PhotoPreviewCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *imageName = self.imagesArray[indexPath.row];
    [cell.photoImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];

    return cell;

}
```

PhotoPreviewCell.m

```
@implementation PhotoPreviewCell

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if(self){

        self.photoImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        self.photoImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 160, 160);
        self.photoImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.photoImage];

    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Please post some code with how do you load the images.

Comment: Personally I'd be explicitly disposing of the images in the clear routine.

Comment: Added some code to hopefully better explain the scenario. What is the clear routine you're referring to, Tony?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so the reason for this is that loading images from flash takes some time and OS tries to avoid loading it on and on, so it's caching loaded images. They're cached only when you're using `imageNamed:` method. If you're testing on simulator release all objects and try simulate memory warning. This should force OS to remove not used images from cache.

Comment: Yes, you're right, imageNamed: is the cause of the problem. imageNamed: caches my images and I lose control over the memory (unlike imageWithContentsOfFile: which does not cache images). So knowing the OS will empty the cache when it needs to (i.e. when the application receives a Low Memory Warning), I shouldn't be concerned seeing my memory footprint increase - because the OS will empty the cache when I receive a memory warning. Is that a correct assumption?

Comment: As long as your memory footprint isn't big enough with loading all of these images you should be ok. If you include them in the bundle try to keep them as small as needed to display without upscaling, this will reduce binary size and memory footprint.